# location.href doesn't work locally on machine?

Tags: c#, javascript

Forget iframes and cross site scripting and all sorts, none of those issues are related to my specific problem.

The problem is in internet explorer (the code works FINE in firefox and similar). Running on a Windows 7 Machine.

Any code like:

```
window.location.href = "http://google.com";
document.assign("http://google.com");
```

Even when the location is a html doc in the current directory (eg: `....href = "nextpage.html"`) it won't allow it.

The error is "permission denied" or sometimes "access denied".

Any reasons why this is happening? Are there any alternatives?

**context** - this is a local html file to be run in a web view in a C# program, so its using IE's engine which is why there is such an issue.

Thanks

Comment: try the `document.location.href`

Comment: however, it looks like kind of "cross site scripting" issue. it is probably illegal for the C# environment to redirect your user elsewhere (the same restriction exists in flash). may be you should add a c# tag, in order c# folks to give some knowledge here.

Comment: I believe IE uses different permissions for files om your computer and is often stricter with them than others. You may be running into this problem and if so digging around IE's security settings might help...

Comment: I've just tested this both in IE 9 and inside a WebBrowser hosted in a C# application and both worked 100% fine.  Can you tell us what IE version you are using and provide more context around what the script is doing and when it is run.